# MLSD/MLST support in IIS FTP service

Tags: iis, ftp

I am searching whether IIS FTP service can support [MLST and MLSD commands](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#page-23) or not, and how to enable that support if possible.

I am testing against a Windows Server 2019 (without FTP Extensibility) and a Windows 10 workstation (with FTP extensibility). In both case, these commands seem unsupported. I get a `500 Command not understood.` when entering them directly, and there are listed in neither `FEAT` nor `HELP` commands output.

(I am worrying about this because some clients like Filezilla have on their [roadmap](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=36597) (since 2015...) to remove support of the `LIST` command in favor or `MLST`/`MLSD`. As they write, these extensions are published since long, so most server should support them. But for IIS, it does not seem to be the case, at least "out of the box".)

Edit: although I had noticed the bottom note of their roadmap "Note the date and its significance.", I had not got it. It was first April. Still, having support for a standardized way of listing directory and files in IIS would be great.

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not support `MLSD`/`MLST`. And it is unlikely it ever will. There was no significant change in IIS FTP implementation for years, possibly for decades.

Comment: IIS Ftp is said, by Microsoft, to have been fully rewritten in IIS 7, which is just above the decade old. So definitely there have been changes in the past decades.  
Anyway, it seems likely an extension using IIS Ftp Extensibility could be written by anyone for supporting these commands, so there could be a way. Unfortunately it seems I may have to code it myself.